# Bat file is missing in jmeter bin folder

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, installation

I just tried to install jmeter - (Apache-j meter-5.1.1) but when I view the bin folder bat file is missing. My configuration details: version of jdk is 12.0.2, my operation system is 64 bit. View the screenshot of bin folder - 
https://www.screencast.com/t/apWQkxP3dD4h

Answer (score 0):

Type [Windows Batch File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) is a file type with extension `.bat`

You have such jmeter file in your screenshot

> A batch file is a script file in DOS, OS/2 and Microsoft Windows.
>
> The filename extension .bat is used in DOS and Window

Comment: thanks  but there is no extension such as .bat in my bin folder how could i start the jmeter

Comment: @paul just execute `jmeter`

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on file type named as Jmeter with type as "Windows Batch File" or else open it from command prompt/terminal.

refer to the attached screenshot.

[Cliek here to open a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZdP5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/jmeter.bat) file can be obtained from [JMeter sources](https://github.com/apache/jmeter) at any time if you removed it by accident.

However in fact you **do have** the file:

[image]

You might want to configure Windows Explorer to [show file extensions](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/26/)

[image]

In general I would recommend launching JMeter from [Windows Command Prompt](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm) as in case of i.e. Java misconfiguration you will not be able to see the output given you launch JMeter by double-clicking the shortcut because it will blink and close immediately.

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans/)